# WideImage e Mysql e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia! Então, estou com um problema chato aqui.

```
$nome_produto       = $_POST['nome'];
$valor_produto      = moeda_mysql($_POST['valor']);
$categoria_produto  = $_POST['categoria'];
$descricao_produto  = $_POST['descricao'];
$estoque_produto    = $_POST['estoque'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `produtos` 
(`id`, `nome`, `descricao`, `valor`, `id_categorias`, `estoque`) 
VALUES 
    (NULL, 
    '$nome_produto', 
    '$descricao_produto', 
    '$valor_produto', 
    '$categoria_produto',
    '$estoque_produto')";

$query      = log_mysqli_query($a, $sql);
$id_produto = mysqli_insert_id($a);

if($query) {

// Diretório de Upload de Imagens 
$diretorio      = 'imagens/produtos/';  

require_once 'wideimage/WideImage.php';

// Nome temporário de upload
$tmp_name = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

// Carrega a imagem a ser manipulada                
$image = WideImage::load($tmp_name);
$image = $image->resize(300, 300);

// Nome
$imagem = $diretorio.$id_produto.".".$extencao;
// Salva imagem
$image->saveToFile($imagem);


$sql = "UPDATE `produtos` SET
        `foto_nome` = '$imagem'
        WHERE `id` = '$id_produto'";

$query = log_mysqli_query($a, $sql);
```

Eu executo o script sem o require_once, require, include, já testei todas essas, do WideImage, e roda normalmente, salva no BD.
Eu preciso fazer o upload e redimencionar, quero mandar o arquivo direto do temp para o Wide, fazer o redimensionamento e depois salvar no servidor.
Não dá certo do jeito que está ai, e não consigo ver o erro. ¬¬

Desde já agradeço

Comment: De sintaxe, realmente não tem erro. Quando executa este script retorna alguma mensagem?

Comment: Veja nos logs se tem algum erro e edite a  publicação acrescentando os logs.

Comment: @rzani Então, ele vai até o primeiro query, grava no banco o INSERT, porém não salva a imagem pela classe, nem faz o UPDATE

Comment: @Inkeliz PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 14208098 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0, alterei o max_post_size para 32mb, e persiste o mesmo, tem vários erros destes diferentes, referente as imagens diferentes que tentei upar.

Comment: Acredito que o ideal seja salvar  a imagem em algum direto (talvez não-publico), e então salvar no banco de dados apenas o nome do arquivo salvo. Mas para resolver o erro do `POST` deve alterar o `post_max_size` e o `upload_max_filesize`. O limite está setado para 3,14MB, enquanto o arquivo enviado possui 14,2MB. Altere ambas as variáveis para 33554432, isso é equivalente a 32MB em Bytes. Depois reinicie o Apache/Nginx apenas por via das duvidas.

Comment: @Inkeliz Então, como disse acima, eu alterei o post_max_size para 32mb, estava com 3mb. Porém não adiantou, continua a mesma coisa. Testei na mesma hora que editei, e testei hoje novamente com o servidor reiniciado. O que eu estou fazendo ai é simples, ou era pra ser. Estou pegando o arquivo direto do POST, editando ele e salvando no servidor. Ai ele salva o caminho. Deveria funcionar.